# Can not read email content from gmail after extracting with python program

Tags: python, email, strip, readable

Hello I have a Python program and it is capable of fetching emails from gmail. Everything works fine, except for the fact that there are a bunch of

```
......"ransition99/xhtml">=0D=0A<head>=0D=

=0A<ml; =0D=0A=0D=0Acharset=3DUTF-8" />=0D=0A<title>Untitled Document</title>=0D=0A</head>=0D=0A=0D=0A=0D=0A<body>=0D=0A=0D=0A<p>=0D=0A border=3D=

"0" =0D=0A=0D=0Asrc=3"......
```

that kind of stuff. Would stripping the email of HTML clean this up? I'm not even sure how to refer to this content, is there a particular language that emails are written in?

ps.. I had to delete some, because i cant post images.

Comment: If you are completely unfamiliar with email, you have some learning curve ahead of you. You should probably learn more about MIME.

Answer (score 2):

It's encoded in [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

```
>>> quopri.decodestring('''=0D=0A border=3D=
... "0"''')
'\r\n border="0"'
```

Comment: thank you!   i just stumbled across quopri... working on implementing it now!